Can't understand where ~76Gb of my disk capacity has gone
I'm trying to free up some disk space on my M1 (2020, 13-inch, 500Gb) and the output of OmniDiskSweeper doesn't add up with df, "Get info" and Disk Utility.
There's only one Data volume that without snapshot and free space has 443Gb(413Gi) used (according to df output and DiskUtility). However OmniDiskSweeper shows that in all of my files take ~367Gb.
$ sudo df -h
...
/dev/disk3s5    460Gi  413Gi   21Gi    96% 2899420 220582240    1%   /System/Volumes/Data
...



So my question is: where are the rest of my Gigabytes?
